# Lambda can have only one expression then why it takes if/else in an expression

Tags: python

I read that lambda can have any number of arguments and it must have only one expression

Take a look at the below code

```
from functools import reduce
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = reduce(lambda x,y: x if x > y else y, a)
print(result)
```

Output

```
5
```

In the above expression, lambda is having if and else both. Is it considered as only one expression ?

Comment: Yes, that's one expression that always produces one result. What exactly is confusing about that?

Comment: I thought if and else both makes two expressions.

Comment: This isn't if/else, this is python's ternary operator, like C's `?:`

Comment: Note that a formal if-else fails: `reduce(lambda x,y: if x > y: x else: y, a)`

Comment: I got the point now. Thanks a lot. If you want you can post this in answer section and i will upvote and approve